# Unable to render a view onPress TouchableOpacity in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to render a view on press a TouchableOpacity but it is not working. Can any please suggest the best solution?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
   
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this._renderMyView.bind(this);
    }

    _renderMyView = () => {
      <View>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
          <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
      </View>
    }

    render() {
        return (
       
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._renderMyView} style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} >
                    <Text style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} >camera</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need specify where it should render. I would have a state variable that changes on your `TouchableOpacity`'s onPress, and in your `render()` return it when the state is true.

Comment: Hey @MattyK14 can you please refactor my code please so that i can understand as i new to react native so please help me

Comment: @sumesh has updated his answer, similarly to what I was talking about

Answer (score 1):

you should return the JSX like this. 
Also give flex 1 to view

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity, Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
    }
}

_renderMyView = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{height: 50, backgroundColor: '#eee',marginTop: 100}}>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
        <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
    </View>
  );

}

render() {
    return (

            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>{this.setState({visible: true})}} style={{marginTop: 50,height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} >
                  <Text style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} >camera</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>

              {this.state.visible ? this._renderMyView() : null}
            </View>

    );
}
```

}

Comment: I am not getting the error i am unable to view the render view

Answer (score 1):

For now, there is no indication that your component can depend on when it should render your view. It can simply solve by:

1. Add state to component, for example: `state = { renderView : false }`
2. add conditionally render, depends on your state:

   ```
   render() {
       return (
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._renderMyView} style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
               <Text style={{height: 50, width: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>camera</Text>
               {this.state.renderView && this._renderMyView()}
           </TouchableOpacity>
       )}
   ```
3. return your view from `_renderMyView()`, so just add return statement for your view.
4. change state when press triggered:
   `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({renderView: true})} ... >`

Answer (score 1):

The way React works is based on state changes, so you always render based on the current state (or props).
If you need to render based on some changes, then you should first alter the state and later render conditionally to the new state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            renderView: false
        }

        //You had a slighty mistake here, you have to assign bind's result
        this._renderMyView = this._renderMyView.bind(this);
        this._onPress= this._onPress.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                {this._renderMyView()}
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._onPress} style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} >
                    <Text style={{height:50,width:50,backgroundColor:'red'}} >camera</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }

    _onPress() {
       //React to the event and change the state
       this.setState({renderView: true});
   }

    _renderMyView () {
        //Render based on the current state
        if(this.state.renderView) {
            return (
              <View>
                  <Text>I am here to returns camera</Text>
                  <Text>More stuff here...</Text>
              </View>
            );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

In order to clarify, each time that `this.setState` is called, the component's cycle life is executed, for more information refer to [the oficial docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html), update section. That is to say:

1. `componentWillReceiveProps()`
2. `shouldComponentUpdate()`
3. `componentWillUpdate()`
4. `render()`
5. `componentDidUpdate()`

**As an additional comment** (for the sake of the example above it is not required), `this.setState` executes asynchronously, that means that in case you need to do something **immediately after** the state is modified, you must pass a callback as a second parameter:

```
this.setState({someProp: 1}, () => {
    console.log('someProp: ' + this.state.someProp); //someProp: 1
});
```

Doing this will produce unexpected behavior:

```
this.setState({someProp: 1});
//You cannot ensure that the state has changed at this point, so the following line could be the expected or the previous value
console.log('someProp: ' + this.state.someProp); //someProp: ???
```

Comment: I don't think that use `this.setState()`  produce unexpected behavior, it will just update state sometime. For this code purpose, in my opinion, using `setState()` without callback is fine, because there is no actions you want to implement when state will change, only to render more few things...

Comment: For the sake of this code, a callback is not needed, it is just added as an additional code. The second example I mentioned, will produce unexpected behavior if you expect the state to have been modified since setState is async, that's why I highlighted **immediately after** the state was modified.
I've taken your comment and I've updated my answer to make it clearer.